# Library cached but not found?

Tags: shared-library

A picture says 1000 words
[image: console log]

Anyone knows what is going on here, this does not make sense to me

Thanks

Comment: How did you determined that the library is "cached"? did you run something like `ldconfig -v | grep libsfml`?

Comment: If ldd finds said library, it means its cached, no? I'll check the ldconfig -v and get back to you

Comment: If you run `sudo ldconfig -v` you will likely find that `ldd libcsfml-graphics.so` then *will* be able to find its subordinate libraries (it's running `ldconfig` - with suitable privileges - that builds the cache)